# Make Init bash: mingw-get: command not found

Tags: substrate

Trying to run make init command on my bash command line. bash: mingw-get: command not found. I tried installing everything in the tutorial. I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Edit: I downloaded chocolately and it fixed it.

Comment: Which tutorial are you on?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as a "package manager": http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using chocolately and it worked.